# How to access only specific elements of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So lets say I have a list like this:

```
myList = ["Sprite", "Fanta", "Coke", "7up"]
```

And I want to access only `myList[0]` and `myList[3]` which are Sprite and 7up. I tried doing it with list slicing but couldn't get it right.

Comment: And whats the problem accessing them with index `0` and `3`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely its not but I'm learning python and I'm just curious is there a way to access them with list slicing or something similar to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myList = ["Sprite", "Fanta", "Coke", "7up"]
sprite, sevenup = myList[0], myList[-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is accessing multiple elements from list knowing the indexes,then you can use `operator.itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
myList = ["Sprite", "Fanta", "Coke", "7up"]
index = [0,3]     # you can add as many indexes(valid ones) you want
print itemgetter(*index)(myList)
```

**Output**

```
('Sprite', '7up')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know the `index` of the words you can search it in this way

```
myList = ["Sprite", "Fanta", "Coke", "7up"]
search = ['Sprite', '7up']

print(' '.join(x for x in myList if x in search))
```

**Output**

```
Sprite 7up
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` for this

```
from operator import itemgetter
f = itemgetter(0, 3)
f(myList)
# ('Sprite', '7up')
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using **Step Slicing** in Python. Here, have a look.

```
myList = ["Sprite", "Fanta", "Coke", "7up"]
print(myList[::3])
```

**Output**:

```
['Sprite', '7up']
```